# Use the same port in mockito for different tests

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mockito

I am trying to write a few unit tests for my project using Mockito, while having a manually assigned port in the base path. To differentiate from the port I use for the actual implementation, I have these lines of code:

```
#[cfg(not(test))]
const BASE_URL: &str = "http://localhost:8765";
#[cfg(test)]
const BASE_URL: &str = "http://localhost:8089";
```

My tests currently look like this (I will skip the actual implementation because there is no need for that):

```
    static INIT: Once = Once::new();

    pub fn initialize() {

        INIT.call_once(|| {
            env_logger::init();
        });
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn existing_deck_new_note() {
        initialize();
        let mut server = Server::new_with_port(8089);

        let deck_exists_mock = get_deck_exists_mock(&mut server);
        let find_notes_mock = get_find_notes_mock(&mut server, EXISTING_DECK);
        let add_notes_mock = get_add_notes_mock(&mut server, EXISTING_DECK);

        // Find existing deck, don't find existing word
        let add_note = AddNotes::new(String::from(EXISTING_DECK), String::from("application"), String::from("εφαρμογή"));
        create_notes(add_note).await;

        // Verify
        deck_exists_mock.assert();
        find_notes_mock.assert();
        add_notes_mock.assert();
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn new_deck_new_note() {
        initialize();
        let mut server = Server::new_with_port(8089);

        let deck_exists_mock = get_deck_exists_mock(&mut server);
        let create_deck_mock = get_create_deck_mock(&mut server, NEW_DECK);
        let find_notes_mock = get_find_notes_mock(&mut server, NEW_DECK);
        let add_notes_mock = get_add_notes_mock(&mut server, NEW_DECK);

        // Don't find existing deck, don't find existing word
        let add_note = AddNotes::new(String::from(NEW_DECK), String::from("application"), String::from("εφαρμογή"));
        create_notes(add_note).await;

        // Verify
        deck_exists_mock.assert();
        create_deck_mock.assert();
        find_notes_mock.assert();
        add_notes_mock.assert();
    }
```

If I run these tests one by one, everything is fine. But the moment I try to execute both of them together, I get the following error:

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: ServerFailure, context: Some("Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)") }
thread 'utils::anki::tests::new_deck_new_note' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: ServerFailure, context: Some("receiving on a closed channel") }', src\utils\anki.rs:169:26
```

I thought that running them in serial would solve the issue, since server was trying to initiate more than once on the same port, but apparently it did not, because if I add **#[serial_test::serial]** on my tests, I get the following error:

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: ServerFailure, context: Some("receiving on a closed channel") }
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: ServerFailure, context: Some("Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)") }', C:\Users\dimit\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\mockito-1.1.0\src\server.rs:211:56
```

I found a couple of example online about mockito, but they are too old and deprecated.

I also tried to find an appropriate function inside mockito library that could help, but there is none. I tried **drop(server)**, tried to mess with TCPStream (I am not sure if this is the right path to follow, but I did anyway). In general, I couldn't find any workaround or example with more than one test at once.

My questions are; first and foremost, how to solve this error and manage to execute all my mockito tests together (parallel or serial, I don't care that much).

And secondly, is there a better way to assign a **BASE_URL**? Coming from a Java background, it seems too messy to interact with implementation's code to add test functionality (even if it is not getting compiled if not needed, the readability is getting worse).

Thank you in advance, if you need more data about it, let me know :)

Comment: Huh? If you are working with mocks, why do you need to spin up a real server on a real port?

Comment: @knittl because you can start mocking only after creating a server like [this](https://docs.rs/mockito/latest/mockito/#getting-started). Do I understand it wrong?